# Syntax for mocking a method with a ref argument

Tags: c#, mocking, ref, moles

I have the problem that I can't mock a method that has a ref argument.
The signature of the method I want to mock away is as follows:

```
class ContractRepository
...
public long GetValueAndIncrement(ref Counter counter)
{
 ...
}
```

I tried to mock it like this:

```
Random myRandomizer = new Random();
var contractRepo = new SIContractRepository();
contractRepo.GetValueAndIncrementCounterRef = ((internalCounter) => Int64.Parse(myRandomizer.Next().ToString()));
```

But the compiler tells me that I am missing the "ref" keyword, but when I try it like this

```
Random myRandomizer = new Random();
var contractRepo = new SIContractRepository();
contractRepo.GetValueAndIncrementCounterRef = ((ref internalCounter) => Int64.Parse(myRandomizer.Next().ToString()));
```

I get an error that ref is an invalid expression

Unfortunately, google doesn't help here. :(
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You simply can't use anonymous methods in this case, because they support neither ref nor out parameters. You need to create a "real" method.

```
public void SetupMock()
{
    Random myRandomizer = new Random();
    var contractRepo = new SIContractRepository();
    contractRepo.GetValueAndIncrementCounterRef = GetValueAndIncrementMock;
}

public long GetValueAndIncrementMock(ref Counter counter)
{
    return Int64.Parse(myRandomizer.Next().ToString())
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You *can* use anonymous methods with the *ref* keyword, just explicitly specify the type in the anonymous method:

```
(ref Counter internalCounter) => Int64.Parse(myRandomizer.Next().ToString())
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember that the current version of Moles only supports ref and out arguments as the LAST argument of a method.

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/molesmanual.pdf

Limitations
The current implementation of Moles has several limitations. These limitations are not
inherent to the approach and might be resolved in future releases of Moles:
 The Moles framework supports only a limited number of method signature—up to 
10 arguments, **where the last argument can be an out or ref argument.** 
Method signatures with pointers are not supported.
 Sealed classes or static methods cannot be stubbed because stub types rely on 
virtual method dispatch. For such cases, use mole types as described in “Mole 
Types” later in this document

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether this is a correct way to apply moles but I did it. And it works.

```
///method get call in unit test
public static void DetermineSprintCorporateLiableCustomer()
{
  COptions p2 = new COptions();  
  MGetCOptions.CustomerInfoCallerOptionsRef = (ref COptions p1) =>
  {
    if (p1 != null && p1 != null && p1.Type.Equals(
      "Data", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
      {
        p1.Type = "P";
        p1.Indicator = true; 
      }
    p2 = p1;
  };
}
```

When this part executed during test run, new p2 is available. Below was my scenario.

```
// need to unit test Coptions.Type="Data"
public static MainMethod(Coptions)
{
  Mclass.Method(ref Coptions);
  If(COptions.Type="B")
    Do something();
}
```

It works with new value but there could be a better way.